# Magento 2 System Upgrade error

Tags: magento2, error, upgrade, magento-2.1.1

I'm trying to update Magento 2.1.0 to 2.1.1 using System Upgrade but I get this error:

> We cannot retrieve information on magento/product-community-edition

How can I resolve this?

Comment: you can just upgrade using command tools. run upgrade command and its easily solved